# Is an "iCloud" email address professional enough?

Tags: email

I have never really used my personal email address publicly and it dates back to 15 year old me being edgy, so this is not really an option.

On occasions when I needed "formal" communication (e.g. internship interview or just university communication) I just used my university or faculty email address (firstname.lastname@university.edu)

Now, this email address won't last forever (so I'm told) and I probably need something more professional than my current personal email.

Unfortunately, a lot of name combinations like first.last@gmail.com initials.last@gmail.com and so forth are already taken. I do however have an iCloud (former me.com) account that should be good enough, where I have both first.last@me.com and lastname@icloud.com.

I'm only a little scared since I'm planning to go into the IT business (after studying CS and all...), that might raise... let's say "prejudice". But I don't want to overthink it either.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

(I know I could just make my own domain for $10, but I don't think it's worth the extra administration hassle. I also think it looks a little cocky, if I don't have any public website or blog to go with it)

Comment: If youre worried about the "icloud" domain specifically, try out gmx.com. Not as widely used as gmail. More availability.

Comment: "I know I could just make my own domain for $10, but I don't think it's worth the extra administration hassle. I also think it looks a little cocky," - it sounds like you already answered your own question. Just stick with whatever email you want to use for professional purposes and don't overthink it.

Answer (score 4):

Most Universities have some kind of Alumni provision that will allow you to continue to use your university email address. You might want to check into that.

Depending on the school, this can end up being a very good perk. I've got a couple of friends who only use their Stanford email accounts for job hunting because it gives potential employers a very fast and clear signal "hey this guy is a Stanford grad."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's professional enough. It's not perfect, but its as professional as the vast majority of others.

iCloud is just as professional as gmail as is any mainstream email provider or ISP. If anything I think it's probably more professional looking than gmail or hotmail. It's the bit **before** the @ that matters, as long as the bit after is not blatantly unprofessional.

your.name@elitegamers.website isn't professional. Neither is sexypaul21@gmail.com, but yourname@icloud.com or me.com is fine. I'd suggest me.com in this case.

Alternately use something like Zoho and your own domain to get something like first@firstlast.com - this is what I use (albeit not that exact combination) and it costs me around $10/year, and looks very professional.